# Eddy-current testing

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-current

I heard it was possible to detect a flaws in conductive materials using two coils carrying the same current in opposite directions.

More precisely, I read it was possible to do so by moving a conductive material at a constant speed on the axis of the two coils, and by measuring the voltage on a third smaller coil (also placed on the same axis).

I understand that the first two coils create a magnetic field, and that moving the material will therefore cause eddy currents. I also get that the presence of flaws will change those currents.

But concretely, how will we be able to know whether the conductive material does or does not have flaws ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [Eddy current testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy-current_testing)

Comment: Thank you, I have already read this. But still, I am not sure I understand what is supposed to be seen on the voltmeter as the conductive material is moving.

Comment: There are many more detail webpage and videos and [here is an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oriFJByl6Hs).